# XSLT / XPath function to remove trailing characters

Tags: xslt, xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have the situation whereby I am displaying an address in an XForm, this address comes to me pre formatted, but occasionally contains a couple of trailing commas, which I need to remove.

Here is my code:

```
    <xf:output id="Address-control" ref="$Address" >
        <xf:label>GP Address</xf:label>
    </xf:output>
```

Which, sometimes produces output like this:

```
 My House, My Road, My Town, , , , ,
```

I need something to strip out the trailing commas so the output becomes:

```
 My House, My Road, My Town
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `replace($Address, '[\s,]+$', '')` should remove any trailing mix of white space and commas.